# HTTP server implementation: Mobile web browsers (e.g. Android standard) stop loading page resources

Tags: android, c, http, mobile, embedded

I've written a little web server for an embedded project that is supposed to provide a web based UI for the device. While everything works fine using a PC browser a mobile browser fails to load all the resources (e.g. css / js / images) that are associated with the page.

My server supports persistent connections w/o pipelining of requests. Currently I have reduced the maximum number of parallel connections to 1, so only one request is answered at a time.

My debug observation is that the client, after first requesting the *.html file and then a style sheet, stops requesting any further resources listed in the head. The client does not disconnect.

Do you have any idea as to what kind of mistake I could be making a PC browser would tolerate and a mobile browser would not?

I just read online that most mobile browsers actually implement and use pipelining. Thinking about it further I figured that my current implementation might have problems coping with pipelined requests. Considering the shortage of memory on my STM32 I reuse the receive buffer as send buffer. I will verify shortly...

...Nope, despite what is said >>>[here](http://www.guypo.com/mobile/http-pipelining-big-in-mobile/)<<<, I cannot verify that the android standard browser, Dolphin or Firefox for Android actually pipeline their requests on a "keep-alive" connection.

One more thing... It works perfectly fine when running the emulator from the Android SDK (at least for Android 4.2.2)

Please comment on any additional information you might need.

Comment: Did you tested with other android browsers? Chrome? Opera? Did you tried the developer features in Chrome? The parallel connections could be a problem since most browsers do multiple connections to get resources faster.

Comment: I tested with Firefox for android, it sometimes loads correctly using that browser. Giving it more connections does not do the trick. I observe the same behavior. Single threading the web server just makes debugging easier.

Comment: Just tested with Dolphin; its the same there.

Comment: Did you actually see the requests in your debug log? There must be something like `GET /css/style.css` etc, are you sure that what you are receiving is not empty? Try to get only one image by typing it directly in your addressbar.

Comment: Yep I already did that. Downloading all the resources one by one works absolutely fine. The problem is that the server is waiting for more data after having served the last request, but is not reading any more requests. It is like the browser stopped requesting.

Comment: Did you analyze the traffic using a hub and wireshark for example? I could imagine that your server is not delivering the last resource before the stop completely. (e.g. a length field is wrong or something)

Comment: I was able to analyze the traffic between my notebook and the device which has its own WiFi access point on board. However, I have no idea how i would go about monitoring the communication between the embedded board and my android device

Comment: I'm now getting a wireless packet capturing interface for wire shark. I use a free web server on my PC called miniweb which serves the site perfectly to all of my android browsers. I hope to be able to discover the problem comparing the communication.

Comment: I also monitored the communication between the embedded device and my PC browser. The browser encounters numerous RSTs during the loading process due to the connection limit. I hope that mobile browsers retry connecting to a server as long as they have at least one valid connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the connection limit!

Some of the credits for this answer go to Eun who had the best hunch. The answer came to me when looking at the connection logs that can be generated by Chrome for Android and viewed by Desktop Chrome.

I found that all resources that fail to be loaded result from the connections being rejected on the server side. That means that request jobs that are queued for a connection that fails due to server-side reset, are not rescheduled for another connection despite other connections being alive and having the "Connection: keep-alive" header field. I can also verify that chrome does not use request pipelining. When connected to a WiFi that is.

Desktop browsers do reschedule failed request jobs and that is why it works with them. I have a workaround that currently solves the problem. However I'm not sure about its portability. I use a java script on the web page that successively adds the required resources by listening for their "load" events.

I will ask another question regarding script-, css-, image- or more general resource loaders that generate my desired behaviour.

Comment: One extra idea: web server may say "Connection: close" in headers and client may open new connection for new request. Yes, 5 years, I know.

Answer (score 0):

To save memory resources on your target platform, try to compress your HTML, javascripts and ect.. I advise you to try with gzip [HTTP compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression). For images try to use or make .svg (Scalable Vector Graphics) images. Then you can also compress SVG images.

Comment: While this certainly reduces the amount of data that has to be transferred it does not solve the problem of multiple connections, I'm afraid, unless there is some way to deliver the complete website (including its resources) gzipped as an archive of some sort. That of course would be great. However, I didn't discover such a method / Content-Encoding in the RFCs